# Solve for a and b? $a = \frac 1{20}(b^2 + 2b + 25)$ and $-a-1=-b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for a and b using two equations:

$$\begin{align} a & = \frac 1{20}(b^2 + 2b + 25)\\ \\ -a-1&=-b\end{align}$$

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't Calculus, it's school algebra. Have you made any effort? Have you ever seen a problem like this solved? What techniques do you have available that might come in handy?

Comment: The initial question was calculus, I simplified to get this. I tried solving for the roots of the quadradic but apparently there were no reals roots

Comment: By "the quadratic", I take it you mean $b^2+2b+25$. OK, so that didn't work --- so try something else! The beautiful thing about math formulas is that nothing gets broken if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

$-a - 1 = -b \iff a + 1 = b\iff a = b-1$.

Now substitute $a$ into the first equation

$$\begin{align} b-1  = \dfrac 1{20}(b^2 +2b + 25)  & \iff 20 b - 20  = b^2 + 2b + 25 \\ \\ &\iff b^2 -18b +45 = 0\end{align}$$

and solve for $b$.

Then back substitute to solve for $a$.

Comment: You're welcome, Jesse!